# Google contact api mobile view issue with get contacts

Tags: javascript, php

I am fetching google contacts using https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly in javascript working fine on website desktop view but when I am changing view to mobile for website this is not working for me please help me to find out this problem with mobile view 
sample code

```
   <script src="https://apis.google.com/js/client.js"></script>
function auth() {  $('.loader').css('display','block')
        var client_id = "<?php echo config::get('app.client_id') ?>";
        var scope = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/contacts.readonly';
        gapi.load('auth', function(){
        gapi.auth.authorize(
       { client_id: client_id, scope: scope, immediate: false }, authResult);

 })
 return false;
  }
function authResult(_Result){ if (_Result && !_Result.error)
{ loadPeopleApi(); }}

function loadPeopleApi(){
   gapi.client.load('https://people.googleapis.com/$discovery/rest', 
    'v2', showContacts);
 }
 function showContacts()
 {
    var request = gapi.client.people.people.connections.list({
    'resourceName': 'people/me',
        'pageSize': 1999,
          'requestMask.includeField':'person.email_addresses,person.names,person.photos',
         'sortOrder':'FIRST_NAME_ASCENDING',

    });
     request.execute(function(resp) {

     })
     }
```

Comment: please provide some samples of your code so that we can help you find and fix bugs

Comment: sample code i provided above